# Regex Match word that include a Dot

Tags: java, regex

I have a Question I have this Sentence for Example:

```
"HalloAnna daveca.nn dave anna ca. anna"
```

And I only wanna match the single Standing "ca." .

My RegEx is like that :

```
(?i)\b(ca\.)\b
```

But this doesn't work and I don't know why. Any ideas ?

//Update

I excecute it with:

```
testSource.replaceAll()
```

and with

```
pattern.matcher(testSource).replaceAll().
```

both doesn´t work.

Comment: How do you execute this regex in java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use it like this:

```
Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b(ca\\.)(?=\\W)").matcher(a).replaceAll("SOME TEXT");
```

Which if you omit the java escapes gives a regex: `(?i)\b(ca\.)\W`.

Every `\` in normal regex has to be escaped in java - `\\`.

Also, before a word you have word boundary (`\b`), but it applies only to a part in String where you have a change from whitespace to a alphanumeric character or the other way around. But in your case you have a dot, which is not an alphanumeric character, so you can't use `\b` at the end. You can use `\W` which means that a non-word character is following the dot. But to use `\W` you need to ignore it in the capture group (so it won't be replaced) - `(?=`.

Another issue was that you used `.`, which matches any character, but you actually want to match the real dot, so to do that you have to escape it - `\.`, which in java String becomes `\\.`.

Comment: This works perfectly ! But i dont understand what a non word boundary means ? can you explain the differenc between \b and \B please ?

Answer (score 3):

You must *escape* the dot and assert a non-word following:

```
(?i)\bca\.(?=\W)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/2dAg4liEVA).